# How do I cURL a npm package into a npm repository onto my local nexus?

Tags: curl, npm, nexus

I created a simple npm package in a directory with the following structure:

random-number-generator (directory name)

- package.json
- index.js

I then used `npm pack` to create my `random-number-generator-1.0.0.tgz` file. I also have a npm repository called npm-hosted.

I need to be able to cURL this package into the npm-hosted repository on my local nexus. I have tried the following command:

`curl -u user:password -X POST "http://localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/components?repository=npm-hosted" -F "npm.asset=C:\Projects\npm-nexus-test\random-number-generator\random-number-generator-1.0.0.tgz" -v`

But I get the following error from the nexus.exe window:

```
2019-09-08 18:57:50,174+0100 WARN  [qtp901422593-77] admin org.sonatype.nexus.siesta.internal.UnexpectedExceptionMapper - (ID dbf90a0a-8c94-4e27-bd20-c902a6f8367f) Response: [500] 'ERROR: (ID dbf90a0a-8c94-4e27-bd20-c902a6f8367f) java.lang.NullPointerException'; mapped from: java.lang.NullPointerException
2019-09-08 18:59:40,793+0100 INFO  [qtp901422593-79] admin org.sonatype.nexus.repository.upload.internal.UploadManagerImpl - Uploading component with parameters: repository="npm-hosted" format="npm"
2019-09-08 18:59:40,795+0100 INFO  [qtp901422593-79] admin org.sonatype.nexus.repository.upload.internal.UploadManagerImpl - Asset with parameters: file="null"
2019-09-08 18:59:40,800+0100 WARN  [qtp901422593-79] admin org.sonatype.nexus.siesta.internal.UnexpectedExceptionMapper - (ID 9db49b76-e338-4aa6-850c-d2deebd15dba) Unexpected exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

And this error from curl:

```
curl -u admin:admin -X POST "http://localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/components?repository=npm-hosted" -F npm.asset=random-number-generator-1.0.0.tgz -v
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8081 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> POST /service/rest/v1/components?repository=npm-hosted HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8081
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 177
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------2766893a4b807008
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
< Date: Sun, 08 Sep 2019 18:13:25 GMT
< Server: Nexus/3.18.1-01 (OSS)
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
< X-Siesta-FaultId: c3cc2a39-9db4-42fc-a11e-25e930ad3cdc
< Content-Length: 79
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
<
ERROR: (ID c3cc2a39-9db4-42fc-a11e-25e930ad3cdc) java.lang.NullPointerException* Closing connection 0
```

It looks like it can't find my file to upload even though I give it the absolute relative file path. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

curl's `-F "field=/some/file"` will literally send a string `/some/file` as the `field` content. To send the file's content you need to prepend it's path with `@` sign, i.e., `-F "field=@/some/file"`. You can find this in [curl's manual](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).